# Is it possible to user OpenCV library with Android 2.1?

Tags: android, opencv

Is it possible to use OpenCV library with Android 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Have a look on [ndk-build-crystax](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php). I am using it to crosscompile my C or C++ codes that use OpenCV functions to run on android.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, share your updates if u are interested. Even I am new to this and learning too. We might be able to help each other.

Comment: Links were helpful, but my team decides to change topic of our project. New topic doesn't require OpenCV. This may be helpful if You are interested: [OpenCV and NDK](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to compile it using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) since it is a C/C++ library. To call functions from opencv you will need to create wrappers and call them from Java using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).